# UITableView is not appearing inside my UITableview's cell.contentView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView class that I'm trying to instantiate in the cell of another UITableView. For whatever reason, it's not appearing or being even being loaded.

```
let words                = self.page.valueForKey(categories[parent])!.allObjects as! [Word]
let wordTableView        = WordTableView(frame: CGRectZero)
wordTableView.delegate   =  self
wordTableView.dataSource = self
wordTableView.words      = words
cell.contentView.addSubview(wordTableView)
```

And my `WordTableView.swift` looks like this :

```
class WordTableView: UITableView {

    var words = [Word]()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "WordCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordCell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return words.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordCell

        let word = words[indexPath.row]
        cell.sanskrit.text = "wazzuuuup"
        cell.definition.text = "my defination station!"
        return cell
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside my WordTableView class, it never gets called.

Comment: r u forget to set the frame of your tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a previous comment mentioned you probably need to set the frame on the `wordTableView`. You will also need to do the following:

1. Call `wordTableView.viewDidLoad`. This will not be called automatically for you. This function only gets called automatically on view controllers.
2. Call `wordTableView.reloadData`.

Something like this:

```
wordTableView.frame = ...
cell.contentView.addSubview(wordTableView)
wordTableView.viewDidLoad()
wordTableView.reloadData()
```